# Finding the angle between two points

Tags: trigonometry

First of all, I am doing some mathematical background information for a software I am creating.

What I want to achieve is the point on an object rotating towards where the mouse is. Like in tank games, where the turret rotated depending on `mouseX` and `mouseY`

In terms of programming, this can be achieved by using the `atan2` function, that returns an angle between two points (I believe).

What I want to do is find the angle between an object, and mouse click.
[image: Example]

Is there a special `maths formula` for this? Because my research on google, brings 'atan2' since I'm a programmer. Since most languages have their own maths library, it is abstraction. I want to know how the formula works, in terms of maths.

**The question is**, what is the formula called for this; to find the angle between two points. So my object can rotate towards the `mouseX` and `mouseY` position

Comment: What do you mesn by " ..point rotating towards the mouse .. " ? Can you add details and elaborate ?

Comment: @SrinivasK You know in video games; lets say a top down 2-D tank game. You can control the rotation of the turret, depending on your mouses position. I want to know what formula is used to calculate the angle between the point that's being rotated on, and the point where the mouses position it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [`atan2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function is an extended version of the trigonometric inverse tangent function. In the figure below, $\tan{\theta}=y/x$, so $\tan^{-1}{y/x}=\theta$. The `atan2` function just calculates $\tan^{-1}{y/x}$ with *y* and *x* as separate parameters. The reason it does so is to give a more accurate answer: since the tangent function is periodic, there are multiple values of *x* and *y* that would appear to have the same angle (but do not). Also, `atan2` provides the correct values when *y*/*x* is undefined, such as at $\pi/2$.

[image: atan2 diagram]

Another way to find the angle you're looking for is to use vectors. Using the *x*-axis as one of the vectors and $\vec{OP}$ as another one, you could use the formula

$$\cos{\theta}=\frac{u\cdot v}{||u||\times||v||}$$

Note that whichever way you use, you need two lines to measure an angle. You would have to choose a reference line to measure the angle $\theta$ with; most commonly one would use the *x*-axis.

Comment: Clear explanation, ticked answer for diagram and the other solution provided.

Comment: Note that the `atan2` function usually takes `y` as 1st argument and `x` as second argument.